# Write the definition of the function print to output the values of the

Tags: c++

Note: I'd ask my teacher for help, but she's only active on Thursdays~Sundays, so that's a long wait..

In class we are currently using:
 C++ Programming: Program Design Including Data Structures

Everything was fine up until I reached the Chapter 10, classes, after re-reading the chapter 2 times, i doubt I'll be able to figure this out myself, on part of our homework it asks that we:

Write the definition of the function print to output the values of the instance variables.

from this:

```
class employee //Line 1
{ //Line 2
public: //Line 3
employee(); //Line 4
employee(string, int, double); //Line 5
employee(int, double); //Line 6
employee(string); //Line 7
void setData(string, int, double); //Line 8
void print() const; //Line 9
void updatePay(double x); //Line 10
int getNumOfServiceYears() const; //Line 11
double getPay() const; //Line 12
private: //Line 13
string name; //Line 14
int numOfServiceYears; //Line 15
double pay; //Line 16
};
```

Would it look something like this?

```
void employee::print() const
{
    cout << employee::employee << endl;
}
```

I guess the real question is, How would you print the employee within a function?

Comment: Just print each member variable in the order you want it.

Comment: I shouldn't be able to do that, since they are private members though, right? So there has to be another way

- Print doesn't have any parameters either, so i can't do that either, i can't change anything in the class.

Comment: A member function function have access to the class private variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print the member variables as usual:

```
void employee::print() const
{
    std::cout << name << ' ' << numOfServiceYears << ' ' << pay << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you a hint:

`void employee::print() const` is a *member function* -- it's a member of `employee`.

The expression `employee::employee` doesn't make much sense.  It looks like a constructor call, but: 1) there are no parenthesis to delimit the constructor's arguments, 2) why would you need to construct an `employee` in an `employee` member function?  (Hint:  you wouldn't.)